# Launching the missiles

Tags: computer-puzzle

The software for launching the missiles was designed so that *both* captain and co-captain had to press their `LAUNCH` button at the same time in order to trigger a launch. During testing it was discovered that if *either* operator pressed their `LAUNCH` button, the missiles would launch.

"I don't get it," said Barbara the software engineer as she looked at the code. "It *clearly* says AND:"

```
if (button1Voltage == HIGH && button2Voltage == HIGH) {
    missileRelay.setVoltage(HIGH);
}
else {
    missileRelay.setVoltage(LOW);
}
```

What was causing the bug?

Comment: Maybe && is not AND but OR.

Comment: If && = OR, then the code is worthless, since any of it could mean anything.

Comment: After recent cutbacks, the military has been forced to use StackExchange for all debugging and Q/A of missile launch systems...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A potential answer:

> The system uses low-true logic, the button value is high only if it isn't pressed, and the missiles are only launched if voltage is low.

Comment: If either of them press the button, both button voltage would be different. Isn't it?

Comment: @MohitJain if either of them press the button, both voltages wouldn't be HIGH anymore, meaning it'd go to the else and launch the missile.

Comment: This is what I thought too

Comment: If so, it's a pretty dangerous missile system; if the power fails to the relay but not to the launching mechanism the missiles also launch :( (unless LOW is still a true voltage I guess)

Comment: If you invert all inputs and outputs of an and-gate, it is the same as an or-gate, which is basically what happens here.

Comment: And the button is in a "LOW" position when you pressed it !

Comment: @Quark If the power fails, what will produce a low enough voltage to launch the missiles?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Good point, though it might be designed that way on purpose, as a last-resort way to trigger the missiles in an attack.

Comment: Either means "a or b", i.e. if one of them or both, does not it? But in your solution, if both of them press buttons at the same (I know ...) time, it would not launch.

Comment: @Quark Very nice work; this is the answer I had in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Surely in a true missile system...

> you wouldn't set the voltage "low" as it could still invoke enough voltage to initiate launch. A more reliable solution would be to "ground" both firing lines using a dual line relay.

Also,

> the inference of a "Captain" implies this is installed on a ship/platform? then it could be the movement of the metal hulled ship passing through the earths magnetic fields, inducing current into the superstructure without suitable degaussing in place.

Just sayin'

Answer (score 3):

Another possible bug:

> button1Voltage and button2Voltage are references to the same variable.

Which could look something like this in C++:

> bool button1Voltage;
>      bool &button2Voltage = button1Voltage;
>      // so now setting either will set them both.

Comment: That would not launch if *either* of them pressed button.

Comment: @Edheldil just added some clarification.  I know this is a huge assumption.

Comment: That isn't valid C; that's a C++ism. (You can achieve the same effect in C by using the preprocessor.)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that

> The values of button2Voltage and button1Voltage are not being reset so they remain HIGH once pressed.

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` operator is potentially

> overloaded to the || operator, making it an OR instead of an AND

Comment: Dear god I would certainly hope not

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the bug is

> in the hardware rather than the software. The buttons have been wired up in parallel rather than in series, and the voltage measurements for both buttons are effectively measuring the same voltage.

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe somewhere in the process the values are coerced into boolean?

```
const bool HIGH=true;
const bool LOW=false;

int main() {
    bool a;
    bool b;

    a=-1;
    b=1;

    if (a==HIGH && b==HIGH) {
        puts("boom!");
    } else {
        puts("...");
    }
}
```

> ... or buttonVoltage has a type with == overloaded to do that coercion on its arguments

Answer (score 1):

Since this isn't the entire source code of the program, it's easy to contrive a scenario in which a bug has been introduced on a new line.

Take this one, for example:

```
button1Voltage = (button1Voltage == HIGH || button2Voltage == HIGH) ? HIGH : LOW;
button2Voltage = button1Voltage;
if (button1Voltage == HIGH && button2Voltage == HIGH) {
  missileRelay.setVoltage(HIGH);
}
else {
  missileRelay.setVoltage(LOW);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking the same as [nikamed](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10499/nikamed) earlier, but there's not too much other code which would help us know that.

Newest idea is:

> Maybe the missiles get launched when the voltage is set to LOW?

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that

> HIGH=2 and LOW=1 ... and LOW is good enough to launch :)

Or even better:

> LOW=-1, HIGH=1 and any nonzero voltage will cause the launch

Answer (score -1):

> HIGH = 0; LOW = 1;

Same result as Quark's answer.

---

Edit:

> To clarify, if the `HIGH` and `LOW` constants were accidentally set the wrong way around in the code, then the desired bug would appear. When neither button is pressed (both `HIGH`), then `button1Voltage == HIGH && button2Voltage == HIGH`, so the missile is set to `HIGH` i.e. not launched. If either or both buttons are pressed, the missile is launched.

.

> This is not quite the same as Quark's answer, but has the same result.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: ok, I've updated the answer